# Dokku postgres: Expose command bug: `The container name "/dokku.postgres.APP_NAME.ambassador" is already in use by container`

Tags: dokku

```
$ dokku postgres:expose wiki-fashion-hasura
docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/dokku.postgres.wiki-fashion-hasura.ambassador" is already in use by container "05ac13c5682af1b1334ffda6d9142c2e577c81f0776c9a0449516d5ca6d55c8d". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I checked docker ps and there is no container 05ac13c5682af1b1334ffda6d9142c2e577c81f0776c9a0449516d5ca6d55c8d

Then when trying to expose again:

```
$ dokku postgres:expose wiki-fashion-hasura
 !     Service wiki-fashion-hasura already exposed on port(s) 729

$ dokku postgres:info wiki-fashion-hasura
=====> wiki-fashion-hasura postgres service information
       Config dir:          /var/lib/dokku/services/postgres/wiki-fashion-hasura/data
       Data dir:            /var/lib/dokku/services/postgres/wiki-fashion-hasura/data
       Dsn:                 postgres://postgres:03baa499ae71ae371a9276536df5fa56@dokku-postgres-wiki-fashion-hasura:5432/wiki_fashion_hasura
       Exposed ports:       5432->729                
       Id:                  89aa118cd1a41fc28170f6de3ed236171d3f3e2d8c019c62f74b2381282284f9
       Internal ip:         172.17.0.8               
       Links:               wiki-fashion-hasura      
       Service root:        /var/lib/dokku/services/postgres/wiki-fashion-hasura
       Status:              running                  
       Version:             postgres:12
```

But

```
telnet <HOST> 729 
telnet: connect to address <HOST>: Connection refused
```

It isn't exposed. (other ports with this same IP are resolving)

How can I debug this further?